# How to play multiple videos in YouTube Player API?

Tags: android, string, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to play a number of videos from YouTube using the **YouTube Player API** in Android Studio. I have the Video Id of each videos in different strings with name of video titles. Now I want the player to play video when each button with video title is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("my_video_id_1");
    }
}
```

Using this method, I don't know how to '**change the string name**' when second button is clicked to play the second video in the same player.

**Any answers are highly appreciated!**

Comment: please provide more code. Like the code you use "when each button with video title is clicked"

Comment: I have more than one video Id's to be played in the single player when each button is clicked. How can I change the video Id in the player.cueVideo(video_id_using_string)

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(string_name_1);
        }
    }

Comment: I am asking for the code written inside your_button.setOnClickListener

Comment: @SabithPkcMnr Are you using YouTubePlayerView or YouTubePlayerFragment?

Comment: I am using YouTubePlaterView

Comment: I just want to know how to change the string name for video id in cueVideo(string_name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, declare an YouTubePlayer instance and initialize your YouTubePlayerView at onCreate.

```
private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      if(youTubePlayer == null){
        youTubePlayer = player;
      }
    }
}
```

Now, provide the video Id corresponding to each button listener.

```
    switch (btnId) {
        case R.id.btnOne:
            playVideo("my_video_id_1");
            break;
        case R.id.btnTwo:
            playVideo("my_video_id_2");
            break;
        case R.id.btnThree:
            playVideo("my_video_id_3");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Finally, play the video

```
private void playVideo(String videoId){
    if(youTubePlayer != null){
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
    }
}
```

Comment: where the switch put?